# JQuery on('contextmenu') for body, but special one class

Tags: jquery, events, contextmenu, jquery-events

I have a big div (whole page) and inside of it I have smaller one:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="tiny"></div>
</div>
```

`div.all` is like a board for me, `div.tiny` is a little rectangle on it.
I want to show my special context menu any time anything (or nothing) in `div.all` will get RMB. But when I RMB on `div.tiny`, I don't want to execute that "default" procedure, but some (even more special) code. I have tried with:

```
jQuery('body').on("contextmenu", ".all", function(){ /* special stuff */});

jQuery('body').off("contextmenu", ".all .tiny"); /* <- tried to turn off my...*/
/*...special stuff for .tiny that way*/

jQuery('body').on("contextmenu", ".tiny", function(){ 
    /* even more special stuff */
});
```

When I run it, RMB on `div.all` or elements inside of it, I get "special stuff" done. But when I click RMB on `div.tiny` I get both "special stuff" **(which I don't want)** and "even more special stuff" (it's so special, how I cannot want it!).

Any solution?

To make life harder, I cannot change the order (the first `jQuery()` for `div.all`, THAN my functions for `div.tiny`) - in my real project things are more complicated and I have to keep that order for some reasons (still it's look pretty reasonable - from global events to precise one).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite simple, you just need to stop the event from propagating further than your `.tiny` handler.

```
$('.tiny').on('contextmenu', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Your code.
});
```

Assuming you may have a whole lot of `.tiny`'s, or they're dynamically generated, you could delegate this event to `.all`:

```
$('.all').on('contextmenu', '.tiny', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Your code.
});
```

Another option is to check the `e.target`.

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', '.all', function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('.tiny')){
    // The target element is not a .tiny div
  }
});
```

Then you'd just have your other normal handler for `.tiny`

Comment: Genius! And I waited 1.5 min for answer that I was looking for an hour by myself. The second option suit me the best. Thank you, Sir :)