# Is there any way to set the onContextMenu attribute for all buttons in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a simple HTML page that is a list of buttons in a table and each button is a link to a website. What I want is that when you left click a button, it opens the link in the same window and when you right click on it, the link opens in a new window.

I've gotten that all working as below. While it does work, I am trying to clean up the code as this looks like it could be done more efficiently though I am not sure how. Right now I have to manually pass "onContextMenu" to every button and have the URL written out twice.

Is there any way to optimize this or clean up the code to be more readable and maintainable?

```
<script>
  function RightClickFunction(url) {
    //alert("You've tried to open context menu");
    window.open(url);
    return false;
  }
</script>

  ...
  ...

      <tr>
        <td><form action="http://amazon.com"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Amazon" onContextMenu="return RightClickFunction('http://amazon.com');"></form></td>
        <td><form action="http://newegg.com"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Newegg" onContextMenu="return RightClickFunction('http://newegg.com');"></form></td>
      </tr>
```

EDIT:

Here is the work in progress for one solution.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input.btn');
        console.log(elems);
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          console.log(elems[i]);
          elems[i].oncontextmenu = function(e) {
            return RightClickFunction(this.parentNode.getAttribute('action'));     
            }
          }
          function RightClickFunction(url) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu: " + url);
            return false;
          }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><form action="http://amazon.com"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Amazon"/></form></td>
          <td><form action="http://newegg.com"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Newegg"/></form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with event binding? This will help you optimize and clean up your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can select all the inputs, loop through them and add event listener to each.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input.btn');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].oncontextmenu = RightClickFunction;
}
```

See it in action here (note, I'm using the `form` action attribute (`this.parentNode.getAttribute('action')`) to assign the URL to the input context menu events):

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input.btn');
console.log(elems);
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  console.log(elems[i]);
  elems[i].oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    return RightClickFunction(this.parentNode.getAttribute('action'));     
    
    }
  }

  function RightClickFunction(url) {
    alert("You've tried to open context menu: " + url);
    //window.open(url);
    return false;
  }
```

```html
<tr>
<td><form action="http://amazon.com">
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Amazon"  />
</form></td>
<td><form action="http://newegg.com">
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Newegg"  />
</form></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this looks like what I want. I've tried implementing your solution (please see new edits) but I am not seeing it work. The right click menu is the standard OS menu. Do you see what I might be doing wrong? (This is Windows 7 and Firefox)

Comment: You're welcome. Do you see any errors in the console? Because the original code works fine in the snippet.

Comment: I see that the snippet is working so I'm sure it is something that I am doing wrong. In the Firefox console I see "NodeList [  ]" which seems to mean that it is not finding the button elements to add the event to, hence why the right click is not working. Is there any way to view the complete example of the snippet so that I can compare it to what I edited in the original question? I probably have missed something.

Comment: That is the complete snippet. Chances are you're calling the script before the DOM is ready, so no elements are found at that point, or you use different class names.

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap that into a window.onload function, or put it at the end of the body.

Comment: Thank you - that is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jQuery library for my projects:

```
 $('input[type="button"').on('contextmenu',function(){
      alert('you made a rightclick');
 });
```

So you have a contextmenu function on every button at your site (NOTE: please include jQuery first!!).

See here for more Information: [JQuery on('contextmenu') for body, but special one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121284/jquery-oncontextmenu-for-body-but-special-one-class)

Comment: Not sure it's worth it using the heavy jQuery for something as simple as this.